# Simple fast way to convert 03/03/2015 to 3/3/2015

Tags: java, date, converters

I need to convert 03/03/2015 to 3/3/2015.

This is my code:

```
public class getCorrectDates {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        List<String> dates = getCorrectDates.getDates("3/2/2014", "03/03/2015");

        System.out.println(dates);

    }

    public static List getDates(String dateStart, String dateEnd) throws ParseException {

        List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
        List<String> formattedDates = new ArrayList<String>();

        DateFormat formatter;

        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date startDate = (Date) formatter.parse(dateStart);
        Date endDate = (Date) formatter.parse(dateEnd);
        long interval = 24 * 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour in millis
        long endTime = endDate.getTime(); // create your endtime here, possibly using Calendar or Date
        long curTime = startDate.getTime();
        while (curTime <= endTime) {
            dates.add(new Date(curTime));
            curTime += interval;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
            Date lDate = (Date) dates.get(i);
            String ds = formatter.format(lDate);

            formattedDates.add(ds);
            System.out.println(ds);
        }
        return formattedDates;

    }

}
```

Output :

```
02/28/2015

03/01/2015

03/02/2015

03/03/2015
```

And i need :

```
2/28/2015

3/1/2015

3/2/2015

3/3/2015
```

There must be a way to get the dates in the array without the zero
in the date and month. How can I do that?

Comment: The documentation suggests using `d` instead of `dd`; does that work?

Answer (score 4):

The following suffices:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/YYYY");
```

As quoted from [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Number: For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

Answer (score 1):

@JuniorCompressor's answer is best choice, my understanding is that you need to convert given date to wanted format if so you can do this:

```
if(ds.startsWith("0")
   ds = ds.replaceFirst("0", "");

ds = ds.replaceAll("/0", "/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse it with one formatter, and format it with another:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("02/02/1984");
String formatted = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy").format(date);
```

The `formatted` variable is `"2/2/1984"`